# How can I get each char in a string?

Tags: c, pointers

I have:

```
char *card[4]; 
gets(&card[player - 1]); // 2 chars at a time (e.g. 2S, 3D, TF)
```

I can print the string by:

```
printf("%s",&card[0]);
```

But how can I get each char from `&card[0]` (e.g. `'2'` and `'S'`)?

Comment: This `gets(&card[player - 1]);` is wrong. And by the way, ***NEVER*** use `gets()`.

Comment: @Marco, why never use `gets()`?

Comment: @GabrielStaples read [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html). It's pretty clear.

Comment: Indeed it is. Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply index them. For instance:

```
printf("%c %c", card[0][0], card[0][1]);
```

However, your example code is wrong (no memory allocated and taking the address calling `gets`).

Instead, do something like:

```
#define NPLAYERS 5
#define LENGTH 3 // 2 + the null terminator

char card[NPLAYERS][LENGTH];
int player = 0; // first player
fgets(card[player], LENGTH, stdin);
printf("%c %c", card[player][0], card[player][1]);
```

This reserves space for 5 players, each with a buffer that can hold 3 characters. In total, 15 bytes.

It would be a good idea to check the return code of `fgets`.

Comment: I cannot do that, the compiler just prompted an exception at printf("%c", card[0][0]);

Comment: How are you initializing your `card` variable? If it is just what you have shown, it is incorrect, because you haven't allocated memory for it and you are not passing the correct type to `gets()`.

Comment: Values are from input, so I try to create an empty array at the beginning. Clearly it is not working. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably the following:

```
char card[3];
fgets(card, 3, stdin);
printf("%c %c", card[0], card[1]);
```

Comment: `fgets` only needs the same amount of bytes that you have, so `card` can be 3 chars instead of 4 (ie. no need to add or subtract 1 which is also harder to track).